# UIViewController Delegate of DataModel Class?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uiapplicationdelegate

I want a UIViewController to be delegate of DataModel.

In my Data Model there is a lazy loading of data from parse when I instantiate it, which basically happens from app delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)` function, and in my data model I am fetching Parse objects by `Query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error:NSError?)` function.

I want the delegates to be called in the success block.
I want to know if it is possible to make a UIViewController delegate of a Data model? and if yes any example.

This is what I am doing currently -

In App Delegate -

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
let dataModel = DataModel()
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    dataModel.handleFirstTime()
    }
}
```

In Data Model Class -

```
protocol DataModelDelegate:class{
func dataDidLoad(controller:DataModel)
func dataHaveError(controller:DataModel)}

class DataModel {
weak var delegate:DataModelDelegate?
var dataApplied = [PFObject]()

func handleFirstTime(){
let appliedQuery = PFQuery(className: "DummyClass")
    appliedQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.userInfo)
        }else{
            dataApplied = success!
            self.delegate?.dataDidLoad(self)
            print(dataApplied.count)
        }
    })
}
}
```

In my ViewController -

```
class tableViewController: UITableViewController,DataModelDelegate { 
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let dataModel:DataModel = DataModel()
    dataModel.delegate = self
 }
func dataDidLoad(controller: DataModel) {
    print("TableView Reload trigger")
    tableView.reloadData()
 }
//There are other TableView Controller related methods
}
```

Comment: How did you get `dataModel` object in your `applicationDidBecomeActive ` where you triggered `handleFirstTime()` function?

Comment: Thanks for response, I have an instance of data model in app delegate.

Comment: From the code it seems fine. Are you facing any issue?

Comment: Thanks for response, and Yes apparently the dataDidLoad function in UIViewController is not getting trigger and the print statement is not getting executed.

Comment: both dataModel objects are different. You are calling the handleFirstTime() from the Appdelegate object and expecting the delegate to fire in the tableview controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code looks all fine at first sight. But problem here is you are setting your view controller delegate on a different object of `DataModel`.

You need to ensure that you are not creating another object of `DataModel` in your `tableViewController` and use the same object you created in your `AppDelegate` as that is the object you used to trigger your `handleFirstTime()` function.

So, your table controller is monitoring object 2 whereas in your `handleFirstTime()`, delegate on object 1 is being called.

As a side note, you can also try with a singleton `DataModel` if you are accessing this object from many places.

Comment: Thank You, will give it a try and update. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help! Please post the results for the benefit of others.

Comment: Perfect it worked, after using the same instance of dataModel from appDelegate I am able to achieve the desired result, thank you for the suggestion about singleton.